# Cannot input to New Console as child process in c

Tags: c, winapi, process

I'm working on Windows 10.

Here's my code based on this document:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

Here is the code of the Parent process (I have modified only `CreateChildProcess()`. The rest are the same):

```cpp
void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{
    TCHAR szCmdline[] = TEXT("ChildProcess");
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create the child process.
    //"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"
    char(*exeName) = "C:\\Users\\kch79\\source\\repos\\MainProcess\\Debug\\ChildProcess.exe";
    bSuccess = CreateProcess(exeName,
        szCmdline,     // command line 
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

    //WaitForInputIdle(piProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

     // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
    if (!bSuccess)
        ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
    else
    {
        // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
        // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
        // of the child process, for example. 

        WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);

        // Close handles to the stdin and stdout pipes no longer needed by the child process.
        // If they are not explicitly closed, there is no way to recognize that the child process has ended.

        CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
        CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);
    }
}
```

And here is the code of the Child process (I have added only `scanf()`):

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

int main(void)
{
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    HANDLE hStdin, hStdout;
    BOOL bSuccess;

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (
        (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ||
        (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        )
        ExitProcess(1);

    // Send something to this process's stdout using printf.
    printf("\n ** This is a message from the child process. ** \n");
    int number = 0;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("%d\n", number);
    //SetConsoleMode(hStdin, ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);
    //SetConsoleMode(hStdout, ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT | ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT);

    // This simple algorithm uses the existence of the pipes to control execution.
    // It relies on the pipe buffers to ensure that no data is lost.
    // Larger applications would use more advanced process control.

    for (;;)
    {
        // Read from standard input and stop on error or no data.
        bSuccess = ReadFile(hStdin, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);

        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0)
            break;

        // Write to standard output and stop on error.
        bSuccess = WriteFile(hStdout, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);

        if (!bSuccess)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

These codes are working well for only `printf()` but not for `scanf()`.

New Console Window created by `CreateProcess()` does nothing.

I want to control the console, but how?

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: and `g_hChildStd_IN_Rd` - this is handle of what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you redirect the input handle of the child process to the pipe through the following code:

```
CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)
......
siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
```

So your child process cannot input in the new console, but needs to be input through the parent process's pipeline. Of course, you can also set the input handle of the child process to `NULL`:

```
siStartInfo.hStdInput = NULL;
```

In this way, you can input in the child process, but at the same time the parent process cannot input messages to the child process.

Of course, it is recommended that you put the following code at the end of the main function, so that you can observe that the parent process gets the input of the child process.

```
WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

The complete code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

void CreateChildProcess(void);
void WriteToPipe(void);
void ReadFromPipe(void);
void ErrorExit(PTSTR);
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;

int _tmain()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation"));


    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create the child process. 

    CreateChildProcess();

    // Get a handle to an input file for the parent. 
    // This example assumes a plain text file and uses string output to verify data flow. 
    g_hInputFile = CreateFile(
        L"D:\\test\\test.txt",
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,
        NULL);

    if (g_hInputFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateFile"));

    // Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
    // Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
    // until the child process is running before writing data.

    WriteToPipe();
    printf("\n->Contents of %S written to child STDIN pipe.\n", L"D:\\test\\test.txt");

    // Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process. 

    printf("\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n");
    ReadFromPipe();

    printf("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

    // The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
    // To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 
    WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}

void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{
    TCHAR szCmdline[] = TEXT("ChildProcess");
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = NULL;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create the child process. 
    TCHAR exeName[] = L"D:\\VS_test_projects\\Project2\\Debug\\c.exe";
    bSuccess = CreateProcess(exeName,
        szCmdline,     // command line 
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 
     // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
    if (!bSuccess)
        ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
}

void WriteToPipe(void)

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE] = "";
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    for (;;)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hInputFile, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

        bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) break;
    }

    // Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

    if (!CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle"));
}

void ReadFromPipe(void)

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for (;;)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

        bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf,
            dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) break;
    }
}

void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction)

// Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
// and exit from the application.
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I understood more about process and pipe by your answer. 
I found a clue to solving my problem.