# Problem with using CreatePseudoConsole to create a pty pipe in python

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, console, pipe, pty

I am trying to make a pty pipe. For that I have to use the `CreatePseudoConsole` function from the Windows api. I am loosely copying [this](https://github.com/iljau/PyEchoCon/blob/9ee176c048078c627e9e1c06b2d986e2444d6287/PyEchoCon.py#L434) which is [this](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/samples/ConPTY/EchoCon/EchoCon/EchoCon.cpp#L91) but in python.

I don't know if it's relevant but I am using Python 3.7.9 and Windows 10.

This is my code:

```py
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, HANDLE, SHORT
from ctypes import POINTER, POINTER, HRESULT
import ctypes
import msvcrt
import os


# The COORD data type used for the size of the console
class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", SHORT),
                ("Y", SHORT)]


# HPCON is the same as HANDLE
HPCON = HANDLE


CreatePseudoConsole = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreatePseudoConsole
CreatePseudoConsole.argtypes = [COORD, HANDLE, HANDLE, DWORD, POINTER(HPCON)]
CreatePseudoConsole.restype = HRESULT


def create_console(width:int, height:int) -> HPCON:
    read_pty_fd, write_fd = os.pipe()
    read_pty_handle = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(read_pty_fd)

    read_fd, write_pty_fd = os.pipe()
    write_pty_handle = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(write_pty_fd)

    # Create the console
    size = COORD(width, height)
    console = HPCON()

    result = CreatePseudoConsole(size, read_pty_handle, write_pty_handle,
                                 DWORD(0), ctypes.byref(console))
    # Check if any errors occured
    if result != 0:
        raise ctypes.WinError(result)

    # Add references for the fds to the console
    console.read_fd = read_fd
    console.write_fd = write_fd

    # Return the console object
    return console


if __name__ == "__main__":
    consol = create_console(80, 80)
    print("Writing...")
    os.write(consol.write_fd, b"abc")
    print("Reading...")
    print(os.read(consol.read_fd, 1))
    print("Done")
```

The problem is that it isn't able to read from the pipe. I expected it to print `"a"` but it just gets stuck on the `os.read`. Please note that this is the first time I use the WinAPI so the problem is likely to be there.

Comment: Be aware that this is a *very* new Win32 API and not even all versions of Windows 10 support it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I had no idea but I am mainly using this project for my computer. Does it use a Win64 API (just guessing)? Also I know that Windows has surprising backwards compatibility. Doesn't that mean that the Win32 API should be supported by all Windows 10 versions?

Comment: All Windows versions back to the 90s use some form of the Win32 API.  But new versions add new functions to the API.  Backward compatibility means that no functions are removed.  This particular function was added in "Windows 10 October 2018 Update (version 1809)" as seen on [the official documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createpseudoconsole).  If you're only running on your own computer and it has a version of Windows 10 with at least that Feature Update applied, you can use it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh that's what you mean. I know that the `CreatePseudoConsole` function is quite new (from 2018) and that is why I am having so many problems with it. I think I will be fine as I am unlikely to switch to other versions of Windows. Do you have any ideas as to what can be causing my issue?

Comment: I don't know the implementation of `os.pipe` in python, but I think the problem is caused by the read and write handle of the pipe, maybe you can refer to: [Cannot input to New Console as child process in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139580/cannot-input-to-new-console-as-child-process-in-c/66148640#66148640)

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT I edited my question with the code that I used to remove the calls to the `os` library. It still doesn't work.

Comment: After my test, I found that the program is blocked in `ReadFile`, I think you can refer to: [We've traced the pipe, and it's coming from inside the process!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110708-00/?p=10203). And according to the official sample, CreatePseudoConsole` does not seem to establish communication between the two pipes. So why must it be necessary use this API?

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT I already knew that the pipes weren't connected properly that is why I asked the question. Also as I stated: *"I am trying to make a pty pipe. For that I have to use CreatePseudoConsole"*. On windows there isn't any other way of creating a pty pipe according to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/).

Comment: Typo: `argtypes`, not `argtype`.

Comment: @user3840170 That's just for annotation. I don't think it matters.

Comment: As I remember, `ctypes` performs type checking and/or conversions based on those. Even if not crucial, I think it’s worth fixing.

Comment: Anyway, as I see it, the main problem is that you’re both writing into and reading from (in Unix terms) the ‘master’ side of the PTY while there’s no program doing the opposite at the ‘slave’ side. You’re writing to one pipe whose reading end is supposed to be held by the program, and reading from another pipe whose writing end is supposed to be help by the program – but there’s no program at the other end of either pipe.

Comment: Try translating the sample at <https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/> or <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session> and see where that gets you.

Comment: @user3840170 Isn't the master side `read_pty_fd` and `write_fd` and the slave side `read_fd` and `write_pty_fd`? From my function I return `read_fd` and `write_fd`. Also that is exactly how [they](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/samples/ConPTY/EchoCon/EchoCon/EchoCon.cpp#L91) do it. Fixing the spelling mistake didn't do anything.

Comment: No, the master side is `read_fd` and `write_fd`, while the slave side is `read_pty_fd` and `write_pty_fd`; it’s the latter two that are converted to a pair of `HANDLE`s and as such passed to the `CreatePseudoConsole` call.

Comment: @user3840170 Ok so what should I pass in to `CreatePseudoConsole` and where should I read/write to?

Comment: `CreatePseudoConsole` is fine. You pass the `HPCON` handle you receive from it to a child process (like the MSDN links tell you to) to connect it to the slave side, while you use `read_fd` and `write_fd` to communicate with it on the master side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230726/discussion-between-thelizzard-and-user3840170).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code: what you got wrong is your expectations.

What you are doing is writing to the pipe meant to feed ‘keyboard’ input to the program, and reading from another pipe that returns ‘screen’ output from the program. But there is no actual program at the other end of either pipe, and so there is nothing the read call can ever return.

The `HPCON` handle returned by the `CreatePseudoConsole` API is supposed to be passed in a thread attribute list to a newly-spawned process via `CreateProcess`. Pretty much nothing can be done with it other than that. (You cannot even connect yourself to the pseudoconsole, as you would be able on Unix.) After the handle is passed in this manner, you can communicate with the process using the `read_fd` and `write_fd` descriptors.

An [article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session) provides a full sample in C that creates a pseudoconsole and passes it to a new process; the [exact same thing](https://github.com/iljau/PyEchoCon/blob/9ee176c048078c627e9e1c06b2d986e2444d6287/PyEchoCon.py#L509-L530) is done by the very source you linked.

Comment: I got it working. I am able to handle most ANSI characters but I am having 2 troubles. If the child process writes to `stderr`, why doesn't the console output an ANSI character to change the colour to red? Also I keep seeing that the console writes a `ESC[nX` where `n` is a number. What is that character?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences covers it.

Comment: Thanks you. I was using [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences) which didn't help me. One last question: why doesn't the `PseudoConsole` colour in text that is written to `stderr`? `cmd` also has the same problem.